# Determine whether $F$ is continuous as a map from $\big({\cal C}[0,1],d_1\big)$ to $\big({\cal C}[0,1],d_1\big)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Define $F:{\cal C}[0,1]\to{\cal C}[0,1]$ by $F(f)(x)=\int_0^x{f(t)\over\sqrt t}\,dt$.

I have a feeling that the map is continuous. I have shown that the map is Lipschitz continuous from $(\mathcal C[0, 1], d_\infty)$ to $(\mathcal C[0, 1], d_\infty)$.

$$\left| F(f)(x) \right| = \left| \int_{0}^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}} dt \right| \leq \int_{0}^x \left| \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \right| dt  \leq \|f\|_\infty \int_{0}^x \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{{t}}} \right| dt \leq \|f\|_\infty \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} dt = 2\|f\|_\infty$$
for all $x \in [0, 1]$.

Thus:
$$\sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |F(f)(x)| = \|F(f)\|_\infty \leq 2 \|f\|_\infty$$

However, the same technique does not seem to apply to $\big({\cal C}[0,1],d_1\big)$.

Comment: Is it a valid map from $(\mathcal{C}\left[0,1\right], d_1)$ to itself? $f\left(t\right) = t^{-2/3}$ does belong to $(\mathcal{C}\left[0,1\right], d_1)$, while the integral defining $\left(Ff\right)\left(x\right)$ diverges.

Comment: @MihailPoplavskyi Your $f$ is not continuous at zero.

Comment: sorry, silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ is not continuous for the $d_1$ metric. Take $f_n(t) = \min\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}},n\right)$, then
$$\lVert f_n \rVert_1 \leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt.$$
But we have
$$\lVert F(f_n)\rVert_1 = \int_0^1 |F(f_n)(x)|\,dx = \int_0^1\int_0^x \frac{f_n(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt dx \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} \int_0^1\int_0^x \frac{1}{t}\, dt dx = \infty$$
by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with wedge products. How is the wedge product defined in $\mathcal C[0, 1]$? $f_n(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \wedge n$?

Comment: This just means the minimum. I edited the post @Benjamin

Comment: Are you saying that $f_n(t)$ converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ by monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: No. $f_n$ converges pointwise and the sequence is nondecreasing, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral